# Flaw in a published binary thinning algorithm

Tags: algorithm, debugging, image-processing

I am using the binary image thinning algorithm found as "Graphics Gems IV. Binary Image Thinning Using Neigborhood Maps", by Joseph M. Cychosz.

An implementation can be found online at https://github.com/erich666/GraphicsGems/blob/master/gemsiv/thin_image.c

I checked it for conformity with the original algorithms, and found no difference.

The algorithm works fine most of the cases, but I observe configurations that make it loop forever.

For example, with the image below it will try forever to erase the pixel at coordinates (0, 7) (marked with a red dot), both in the directions 0 (North) and 2 (West).

[image]

When the looping begins, the configuration is as below (caution, different pixel size). I don't see anything remarkable there, except that we are along an edge.

[image]

Has anyone faced this problem and found a fix ?

Comment: How can this question be too broad ???

Comment: Thank you for the silent downvote, that's really friendly.

Comment: (`too broad` - not by leaving _Efficient_, _h_ and _u_ from the title…) Have you tried to crop the map shown above (16*16, 8 by 12)?

Comment: @greybeard: "(too broad - not by leaving Efficient, h and u from the title…)": no idea what you mean. Is there a pun ?

Comment: @greybeard: the sample case is already a crop of a larger image (that shows the same behavior). The problem is not size-dependent.

Comment: `Is there a pun ?` Far as I can tell, the title was _Efficient Binary Image Thinning using Neighbourhood Maps_ - your neighbour may be fine without a _u_, but looks overly thin without the _h_.

Comment: `The problem is not size-dependent.` `the sample case is already a crop` - It would be interesting what _is_ the minimum case to trigger this. My guess is that it already occurs with the left four pixels from the input from three pixels above to three pixels below the position marked. That said, thinning algorithm are hard pressed with "checker-board" situations (second row, 6 pixels from the right).